# Articles and Prepositions: “At/The mountain of…” and "…descended in/on her head"

Tags: prepositions, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

> **The/A** mountain of family responsibilities had already descended
>   **in/on** her head.

According to me, it is **in her head**.

---

But I am not 100% sure about the answer because in the net various answers are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A mountain & on her head.**

Normally you will use *on head* if it's something like a responsibility because its more vocal than literal that those responsibilities fall.

So it's

> A mountain of family responsibilities had already descended on her head.

Comment: so why is it **A** and not **The**?

Comment: Because it's indefinite. We won't know what are those! You can probably list those responsibilities but you can't be certain about the list.

Comment: So What should be added to the above to use **the**?

Comment: The problem had already descended on her hear. When you know about the problem. It's definite!

Comment: So the responsibilities are not specific? So, we must use **the** only when responsibility is mentioned, for eg, the responsibility of taking care of his/her family?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

**On** for the sentence as written.

Reason: “Descend in” implies that the problems are already in her head and are moving. I think you mean that the problems are coming to her and collecting in her head. If you want to emphasize that the problems are *in* her head, I suggest

> ...already *accumulated* in her head.

or, if you want to keep “descended”

> ...already descended *into* her head.

Comment: The OP's sentence looks like a typical English grammar question taken from a textbook, so they may not be able to rephrase the sentence.